# Заменить все двойные пробелы одинарными в XML файле

Tags: c#, xml

В XML десятки и сотни тысяч тегов, и зачастую между слова бывает более 1 пробела так: `<tag>Дядя    Вася   живет    в    городе   таком-то</tag>`

Подскажите как заменить пробелы и сохранить результат?!

"Заменить как в Wordе ctrl-h (2 пробела на 1 пробел).

Жмем несколько раз "заменить все" до полной замены."

Когда я задавал этот вопрос, то ответ мне казался элементарным как замена в ворде, а оказалось как всегда  - дискуссия )

Comment: Пробелы в тегах не учитываются при чтении XML.

Comment: Если вы хотите переформатировать XML, десериализуйте его, и сериализуйте назад, задав подходящие опции сериализации. Но в общем-такая операция не имеет особого смысла, пробелы всё равно почти всегда не учитываются.

Comment: Просто заменить двойные пробелы как в Worde

Comment: _"бывает такое <tag>Дядя"_ -- а если перед Дядя много пробелов, то их надо все убрать или только повторы, т.е. останется один пробел вместо нескольких?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чем именно вы видите проблему**?

Comment: @Krom Stern проблема в подряд стоящих нескольких пробелах

Comment: В чем именно проблема, вы не знаете как открыть файл, как убрать из него символ, как .. что-то еще?

Comment: @Krom Stern уже помогли на с#. Сейчас проверю коды на практике и поставлю галочку. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Xml - это текст. Текст может состоять из одной строки, а файл занимать несколько Gb. Т.е. при загрузке первой строки такого текста возможна ошибка `OutOfMemoryException`.  В такой ситуации, если из текста надо убрать все лишние/сдвоенные пробелы, то пишем так:

```cs
var root = @"C:\Temp\";
var en = Encoding.UTF8;
using (var r = new StreamReader(root+"test.xml", en))
using (var w = new StreamWriter(root+"test.result.xml", false, en)) {
    char prev = '\0';
    while(r.Peek() >= 0) {
        var ch = (char)r.Read();
        var ws = Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch);
        if (!ws || prev != ch) w.Write(ch);
        prev = ch;
    }
}
```

---

Если в файле `test.xml` есть, например, следующий xml

```
<Grid       Background="Transparent">
             <Path   Name="Path">   1   2      3      </Path>
</Grid>
```

получим `test.result.xml`

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
 <Path Name="Path"> 1 2 3 </Path>
</Grid>
```

---

Пробелы бывают разные, хотя и похожи. См. [Whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).
Ниже список некоторых пробелов и соответствующий code point.

```
' '  U+2004   
' '  U+2000  
' '  U+2007   
' '  U+0020
```

Чтобы из code point, например, U+0020 получить char, пишем `var ch = '\u0020';`

Comment: Осторожнее с `Char.IsWhiteSpace` - он разделители строк тоже пробелами считает. В итоге файл при обработке заодно преобразуется из формата винды (CR+LF) в формат мака (CR) :) Возможно, имеет смысл проверять `Char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch) == UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator`

Comment: Или же можно не заморачиваться, а просто проверить как `ch == ' '`. раз уж в требованиях сказано убирать пробелы, а не пробельные символы.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, автору вопроса нужна смена форматирования, не изменяющая смысл самого XML. Поэтому без честного разбора не обойтись.

Comment: @VladD _"Добавил альтернативный ответ (хотя кода многовато)."_ -- я тоже добавил [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489637/196972). в нем сохраняются пробелы в cdata и при preserve.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35442/discussion-on-answer-by-stack-------xml-).

Answer (score 2):

Окей, вот этот подход основан на честном разборе XML без чтения документа полностью в память.

Код читает XML-ноды по одной и копирует в выходной поток всё, кроме незначащих пробелов. Я не уверен, что обрабатываю правильно все особые ситуации, но я проверял пространства имён, комментарии, `xml:space="preserve"` и CDATA.

```
static void RepackXml(TextReader sr, TextWriter sw)
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings()
                                             { Indent = false }))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName,
                                             reader.NamespaceURI);
                    writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                    if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                    writer.WriteWhitespace(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                    writer.WriteCData(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                    writer.WriteEntityRef(reader.Name);
                    break;
                default:
                    // если вылетело здесь, добавьте обработку текущего reader.NodeType
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На вот таком исходном XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.org" xmlns:lala="http://example.org/lala">     
<selfcontained/><self contained="true"/> <inner element="1">    content
      and more content</inner>       <lala:another>
   </lala:another> <!--      I'm comment! --> <spacetest>      </spacetest> <spacetest
 xml:space="preserve">      </spacetest> and 
 <cdata>     <![CDATA[lala     fafa! <>><><><><><>>>>>>>>>]]></cdata></root>
```

выдаёт такой результат:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><root xmlns="http://example.org" xmlns:lala="http://example.org/lala"><selfcontained /><self contained="true" /><inner element="1">    content
      and more content</inner><lala:another></lala:another><!--      I'm comment! --><spacetest></spacetest><spacetest xml:space="preserve">      </spacetest> and  <cdata><![CDATA[lala     fafa! <>><><><><><>>>>>>>>>]]></cdata></root>
```

Имея парсер, можно осмысленно настраивать его как угодно. Например, если мы хотим убрать пробелы из секций с контентом, мы делаем так:

```
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    writer.WriteString(CompressSpaces(reader.Value));
                    break;
```

с таким вот компрессирующим кодом:

```
static string CompressSpaces(string s)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    var prevSpace = true;
    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        var isSpace = char.IsWhiteSpace(c);
        if (!(prevSpace && isSpace))
            sb.Append(isSpace ? ' ' : c);
        prevSpace = isSpace;
    }
    return sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
}
```

Эта модификация на тех же исходных данных даёт вот что:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><root xmlns="http://example.org" xmlns:lala="http://example.org/lala"><selfcontained /><self contained="true" /><inner element="1">content and more content</inner><lala:another></lala:another><!--      I'm comment! --><spacetest></spacetest><spacetest xml:space="preserve">      </spacetest>and<cdata><![CDATA[lala     fafa! <>><><><><><>>>>>>>>>]]></cdata></root>
```

---

Код `RepackXml`, как оказалось, практически полностью повторяет [код `XmlWriter.WriteNode`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriter.cs,de75010c27d4513b). Поэтому если вам не нужна особая обработка отдельных типов атрибутов, имеет смысл радикально упростить код, воспользовавшись `WriteNode` напрямую, как это сделано в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489637/10105).

Comment: _"На вот таком исходном XML"_ -- если XML в файле, то из-за  `version=\"1.0\"` будет `XmlException: "'\\' is an unexpected token`

Comment: @Stack: Тьфу, не убрал экранирование. Спасибо!

Comment: @Stack: Исправил.

Comment: чтобы не писать `switch (reader.NodeType) { ... }` можно наследовать XmlTextWriter и переопределить в нем необходимые методы. см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489637/196972)

Comment: @Stack: Добавил ссылку на ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо убрать лишние пробелы в XML файле и при этом сохранить пробелы в CDATA и в тегах с атрибутом xml:space="preserve" и внутри тегов `<!-- -->`, то можно использовать метод Xml.MapText

```cs
// #r "System.Xml"
using System.Xml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var root = @"C:\Temp\";
Xml.MapText(
    root+"test.xml",
    root+"test.result.xml",
    (t, str) => {
       if (t == XmlNodeType.Comment) return str;
       return Regex.Replace(str, "\\s+", " ").Trim(); 
       });
```

Реализация Xml.MapText

```cs
public class Xml {
  class XWriter : XmlTextWriter {
    Func<XmlNodeType,string,string> map;
    public XWriter(String fname, Func<XmlNodeType,string,string> map)
      : base(fname, Encoding.UTF8) {
      this.map = map;
    }
    public override void WriteString(string text) {
      base.WriteString(map(XmlNodeType.Text, text));
    }
    public override void WriteComment(string text) {
      base.WriteComment(map(XmlNodeType.Comment, text));
    }
    public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count) {
      buffer = map(XmlNodeType.Text, new String(buffer, index, count)).ToCharArray();
      base.WriteChars(buffer, index, buffer.Length);
    }
  }
  public static void MapText(string src, string trg, Func<XmlNodeType,string,string> fn) {
    var rs = new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreWhitespace = true };
    using (var r = XmlReader.Create(src, rs))
    using (var w = XmlWriter.Create(new XWriter(trg, fn)))
      w.WriteNode(r, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Очень симпатично, кстати. Оказывается, `WriteNode` делает [почти так же, как я](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriter.cs,de75010c27d4513b) (кроме отличного трюка с [чтением строк по кускам](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriter.cs,387)), так что имеет смысл не изобретать велосипед, и сделать как у вас. Я бы только не разделял логику преобразования на части, а поместил бы `map` в `XWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.xml", Encoding.Default))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("TestFileNew.xml", false, Encoding.Default))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            int startIndex = 0, findIndex;
            while ((findIndex = line.IndexOf("  ", startIndex)) >= 0)
            {
                line = line.Remove(findIndex, 1);
                startIndex = findIndex;
            }
            sw.Write(line);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: если xml файл, например, на 3 Gb и в нем нет переводов строк, т.е. все 3 Gb - это одна строка, то возможен OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, автору вопроса нужна смена форматирования, не изменяющая смысл самого XML. Поэтому выбрасывать парные пробелы, не обращая внимание на формат, неправильно.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Похоже, мы не понимаем вопрос.